# Accessing SVN via git-svn, both LDAP-authenticated

Tags: git, svn, ldap, git-svn

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709474/using-ldap-as-auth-method-to-manage-git-repositories) explains how to setup LDAP authentication for git.

Now, is it possible for git-svn script to somehow pass the LDAP authentication token to SVN, which is also using LDAP-backed authentication?

What I would like to achieve is when a git user pushes to git-svn repository (authenticating via LDAP), it automatically commits the change to SVN using the same authentication data.

I don't have access to SVN server-side configuration (would be possible, but it is not trivial).

Our current setup uses git user.name and git-svn server stored passwords to authenticate to SVN, but that is troublesome due to the corporate password change policy (users need to update passwords manually, which they keep forgetting about).

Comment: `git-svn` repositories should not be receiving pushes. Even if you could get the authentication working, pushing to an `svn` server from a remote `git` repository isn't likely to be reliable anyway.

Comment: @qqx read my question again - we are using such a setup already with no problems, the only thing missing is seamless LDAP authentication

Comment: Just because you haven't had any problems so far doesn't mean that it's not a bad idea and won't have problems eventually.

Comment: Can you please be more specific, other than "it's not possible"?